# How deep does realloc free when it copies my data in memory?

Tags: c

In the code sample below does the realloc free the memory I allocated for my 10 strings "1234567890" when it moves my p1 or do I have a leak ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char **p1 = NULL;
    char *p2 = NULL;
    int i;

    p1 = (char **) malloc ( 100 );

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
    {
        p1[i] =  (char *) malloc(10);
        memcpy ( p1[i], "1234567890", 10 );
    }

    p2 = malloc ( 100 );

    p1 = (char **) realloc ( p1, (1000 * sizeof(**p1)));

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
    {
        fprintf ( stdout, "p1: %s\n", p1[i] );
    }

    free(p1);
    free(p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`realloc` only goes one-level deep. It doesn't even know you're passing it a pointer-to-pointer, since its argument is converted to `void*`, its parameter type. As far as `malloc`, `realloc` and `free` are concerned, memory is just a flat array of bytes. If you store pointers in memory, that's you choice, but `malloc` doesn't care.

However, the memory leak doesn't occur until the `free(p1)`, which also does not recurse into the array of pointers. (`realloc` will still copy the pointers stored in the buffer, if the block is enlarged. When it's shrunk, you're in trouble.)

Also, your program's behavior is undefined because you don't check for error returns, and the following only works when `sizeof(char *) < 10`:

```
p1 = (char **) malloc ( 100 );

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i ++ )
{
    p1[i] =  (char *) malloc(10);
    memcpy ( p1[i], "1234567890", 10 );
}
```